# Symmetric algebra of a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: tensors

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $G$ be a group acting on $V$. Let $S(V)$ be its symmetric algebra and if we fix a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$ we can identify $S(V)$ with the polynomial algebra with indeterminates $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ that is $\mathbb{K}[ v_1, \ldots, v_n]$. How can we extend the action of $G$ to $S(V)$ and so to $\mathbb{K}[ v_1, \ldots, v_n]$ ?  Please help me. I am confused of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $g \in G$ put

$$
g (v_1 v_2 \cdots v_n)=g (v_1) g( v_2) \cdots g(v_n).
$$
Also $g$ acts as  a linear map.

Comment: Are you defining from $\mathbb{K}[ v_1, \ldots, v_n]$ to $\mathbb{K}[ v_1, \ldots, v_n]$?

Comment: yes, $g: S(V) \to S(V)$

Comment: That is a typical monomial $v_1^{e_1}v_2^{e_2}\ldots v_n^{e_n}$ is mapped to $g(v_1)^{e_1}g(v_2)^{e_2}\ldots g(v_n)^{e_n}$. Am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly....